# Can I map multiple buckets with multiple topics in a single Kafka-Connector S3 sink connector?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka-connect

Google didn't help me, so I want to ask you. I have a lot of kafka topics, and I want to store the messages of a particular topic in a particular S3 bucket.

Do I need to create an S3 sink connector for each bucket or can I configure all the stuff in a single S3 json file (map a bucket with a topic)?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: So one bucket per topic, or multiple topics into one bucket?

Comment: One bucket per topic. :)

Answer (score 2):

The S3 bucket name is [specified per-connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/configuration_options.html#s3), so you will need to create one connector per bucket.

Note that you can specify multiple topics per connector (`topics` / `topics.regex`), so if you wanted multiple topics going to *one* bucket (but different paths), you could do this with a single connector. But for multiple buckets, you'll need multiple connectors.

Comment: Hey @robin , for multiple topics in single s3 bucket, do we just need to add topics.regex : (SAP|EQ).* or we need any other config as well ?

Comment: @KanikaM please post a new question. Thanks.